# Will vs Would examples doubt

Tags: past-perfect, future-perfect, will-would

**1. First Doubt:**

> I will have broken for lunch by 12:30.

This above sentence is from a grammer book, I think *will* should be *would*, for eg,

> I would have broken for lunch by 12:30.

Am I wrong?

**2. Second Doubt:**

also, here is another example from grammerly website explaining will vs would:

> If aspirin will ease my headache, I will take a couple tonight instead
>   of this horrible medicine.

I feel like this above sentence is wrong somehow, I think it should be reworded like this:

> If aspirin could ease my headache, I would take a couple tonight instead
>   of this horrible medicine.

Again, am I wrong? if yes, then why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are wrong. "Will" indicates an intention to do something in the future or a prediction that something will happen. "Would", on the other hand, indicates the _past conditional_, that is something that could have happened in the _past_ but did not. The examples are correct.

Comment: @BoldBen, "If I were elected president next year, I would cut the cost of education. "
does this sentence seem appropriate? I mean, would is being used in future.

Comment: It is highly appropriate and it is future conditional. The difference is that it does not say "if...would _have_..." which is the past conditional. The difference between "If...will" and "if...would" is that "will" indicates a definite intention but "would" indicates conditional intention.

Comment: ok, that makes perfect sense. Thanks man for this explanation. Really appreciate it. :))

Comment: @BoldBen, in the grammer book that I am reading, it says that would is the past tense form of will, among other things but I can't find a single scenario where would is truly being used in the past tense.
Would you be able to give me a single scenario where would is truly being used in past tense?

Comment: @BoldBen, here are 3 past tense examples that I found online:
"I said I would help you."

"He told me he would be here before 8:00."
"When I was a kid, I would always go to the beach."
The problem with these three sentences is that it's basically "Back to the future", as in another sentence (I said; He told me; When I was a kid) is doing the task of going back in the past and would is just bringing us into the future but from that past point in time.
Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes, it is the past tense but it is also used in the _future conditional_ mode, the future conditional uses other words such as 'will' and 'should' as well but 'would' is one of the future conditional forms. Take a look at [this website](https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html) but be sure to look at all of it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions could be valid, depending on circumstances.

At 11 a.m. you could say "I will have broken for lunch by 12.30."

That afternoon, you could say "I would have broken for lunch by 12.30, but I was in a meeting which overran and I couldn't get away until 1.15."

As regards (2), the first version suggests that you think the aspirin will help, the second that you don't think it will and so you don't intend to try it.

Comment: oops, silly question. :P
Now that I read it again after your explaination, I feel stupid. :P Thank You very much for your explaination. :)

Comment: also, one more question: doesn't it seem inappropriate to use "if" with "Will" in the sentence: "If aspirin will ease my headache." ?
I mean, will is used for certainty so wouldn't it make more sense to say it like "if aspirin can ease my headache"?

Comment: "If I were elected president next year, I would cut the cost of education. " is this an appropriate use of would? To describe something in the future?

Comment: It is describing a _hypothetical_ situation. A candidate confident of being elected could say "When I am president, I will...". Everyone else says "If I were president, I would...".

Comment: ok, that makes sense; so could we have said it like: "If aspirin would ease my headache, I would take a couple tonight instead of this horrible medicine."

I guess not, right?

So basically, we use will even in hypothetical situations when we think we are certain about something, otherwise we use would in hypothetical situations. Correct?

Comment: A doctor tells you "Aspirin will ease your headache," so you say "OK, if it will do that, I will take some tonight." Saying "If it would" or "If it could" implies that you believe that it won't or can't.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank You for your help.

Comment: In the grammer book that I am reading, it says that would is the past tense form of will--among other things--but I can't find a single scenario where would is truly being used in the past tense. Could you please give me a single scenario where would is truly being used in past tense?

Comment: Here are 3 past tense examples that I found online: "I said I would help you." "He told me he would be here before 8:00." "When I was a kid, I would always go to the beach." The problem with all these sentences is that it's basically "Back to the future", as in another sentence (I said; He told me; When I was a kid) is doing the task of going back in the past and would is just bringing us into the future but from that past point in time. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: 'I would always go to the beach' = I habitually went to the beach.